# Ggplot2: coord_polar() with geom_col()

Tags: r, ggplot2, polar-coordinates

I have an issue when using `coord_polar()` together with `geom_col()`. I have degree values ranging from 0 to <360. Let's say there are in steps of 20, so `0, 20, 40... 340`. If I plot them with `coord_polar()` I have two issues:

- values 0 and 340 touch each other and don't have the same gap as the other columns
- the "x-axis" is offset slightly, so that 0 does not point "north"

See this minimal example.

```r
suppressWarnings(library(ggplot2))


df <- data.frame(x = seq(0,359,20),y = 1)

ninety = c(0,90,180,270)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black",fill = "grey") +
  geom_label(aes(label = x)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ninety) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = ninety, colour = "red") +
  coord_polar()

p
```

[image]

If I set the x-axis limits, the rotation of the coordinate system is correct, but the column at 0 disappears due to lack of space.

```r
p+scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,90,180,270),limits = c(0,360))
#> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which
#> will replace the existing scale.
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the space occupied by each bar is 20 degrees, you can shift things by half of that in both scales and coordinates:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black",fill = "grey") +
  geom_label(aes(label = x)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = ninety,
                     limits = c(-10, 350)) + # shift limits by 10 degrees
  geom_vline(xintercept = ninety, colour = "red") +
  coord_polar(start = -10/360*2*pi) # offset by 10 degrees (converted to radians)
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1):

I got it closer to what you want, but it's a bit of a hack so I don't know if it's a great solution.

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(x = seq(0,359,20),y = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x+10,y, hjust=1)) +
  geom_col(colour = "black",fill = "grey") +
  geom_label(aes(x=x+5,label = x)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0,90,180,270),limits = c(0,360)) +
  coord_polar()
```

Instead of plotting the geom_cols's at c(0,20,40,...) I'm now plotting them at c(10,30,50,...). I'm plotting the geom_labels at c(5, 15, 25,...).

The label positioning at the bottom of the chart is still not perfect since 180deg is not South.

I get this graph:
[image]